# How can I get Pywinauto type_keys() to work with named keys, eg {VK_TAB}

Tags: python, powerbi, pywinauto

I'm using pbixrefresher to automate refresh of a PBI report, which works perfrectly, however I also need to save a data table as a csv file, by copying the table into excel and then saving as csv since the table is to large to export as csv in PBI (circa 60k rows). I can get pywinauto to go to the data view in PBI but I then need to use Shift+TAB to highlight the table and bring up the Copy Table option. 
From looking at the information available on pywinauto I believe that 
type_keys("+{VK_TAB}",win) is what I need to use to do this, however I get the following error message:
pywinauto.keyboard.KeySequenceError: '}' not found

I have tried {TAB}, as well as different bracket types and no brackets but none of these work (using no brackets gave no error but nothing happened).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found several inconsistencies when attempting to use the symbolic versions of ctrl(^), shift(+) and alt(%). In the [documentation](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html), it states to use down and up, appended to the input, as this will hold down the shift key while whatever is inbetween is pressed. I've had to do this in several places with the ctrl key. This is done like so:

```
type_keys("{VK_SHIFT down}{VK_TAB}{VK_SHIFT up}")
```

This will hold down the shift key while tab is pressed.

Comment: Thanks jkwhite, I tried your suggestion but I continue to get the same error:                                                       

KeySequenceError: `}` not found

Comment: jkwhite, actually it does work. I just tried it again outside of the def type_keys function in pbixrefresher, so as win.type_keys("VK_SHIFT down}{VK_TAB}{VK_SHIFT up}") instead of type_keys("{VK_SHIFT down}{VK_TAB}{VK_SHIFT up}", win) and that works perfectly. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works. I should have mentioned that that's how I use the type_keys as well. I've never tried to use type_keys("foo", win).